# How do you apply filter or sort rules in Angular Smart-Table when using a repeater over entry pairs

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a data structure that like the following that I'm storing in FireBase:

```
{ 'assets' : {
    'key1' : {
        'name':'application1',
        'deployed':'dev'
    },
    'key2' : {
        'name':'application2',
        'deployed':'prod'
    }

} }
```

I have pulled in angular smart-table and have the following table structure:

```
<table st-table='assets'>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Deployed</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="(assetId, asset) in assets)">
        <td>{{asset.name}}</td>
        <td>{{asset.deployed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This all seems to work great but if i try to add sorting using

```
<th st-sort='name'>
```

or if I try to add searching/filtering using

```
<th><input st-search='name' type='search'/></th>
```

Nothing happens and I see no javascript failures or anything else.

My suspicion is this has something to do with the repeater using a key/value pair rather than a normal object. I've tried using 'asset.name' but I get the same results and with no output or errors I'm not sure where to go next.

Thoughts/Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is easily done with orderBy, sort and a filter. Give me a few minutes and I will code up a quick example...

Answer (score 0):

Using orderBy and filter you can get the results you are looking for

In your controller, place the following:

```
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFilter = '';     // set the default search/filter term
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchFilter">

<table st-table='assets'>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        Name
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </th>
    <th>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'deployed'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        Deployed
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'deployed' && !sortReverse" class="caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'deployed' && sortReverse" class="caret-up">
      </a>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="(assetId, asset) in assets | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFilter">
      <td>{{asset.name}}</td>
      <td>{{asset.deployed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There may be some minor errors here since I am currently on my phone away from the office. This should get you pretty close to what you are looking for though.